# Remote Java Debugging with Eclipse's Remote System Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone have experience debugging java code (code lives on remote Linux server) using Eclipse's Remote System Explorer? I'm able to explorer files and use the built in shell but I can't get it to stop on any breakpoints within the eclipse ide.

Comment: Whats the remote server you are trying to debug? I have experience with debuging java code on remove jboss instances. To do that, you need to start jboss with some extra flags to allow eclipse to hook in.

Comment: I don't have an app server that's running a web app, just running a class that has a java main and some junit...all command line executable stuff...

Comment: Then why bother with the remote debugger? You just want to use the standard debugger within eclipse. Then it occured to me it maybe a long lived process on the remote server. Is this the case? Not something you can just debug within eclipse?

Comment: The java class is using JNI that uses several Linux specific libraries so its a mess trying to compile that locally.  Thats why I'm at where I'm at...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a punt that your remote java server needs to be started using something like:

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y  suspend=y -jar stockTradingGUI.jar

Then you will be able to connect using the eclipse remote debugger

For a full run down see: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html

Comment: so I would need the stockTradingGUI java project in eclipse, compile and deploy the stockTradingGUI.jar onto the remote system then run the above command on the remote system, then connect via a debug configuration in Eclipse?  Am I following correctly?

Comment: No you need to modify the startup of the process on the remote computer to have start parameters similar to this, then you need to configure eclipses remote debugger to point at that host, and the port configured above. I have edited the above to have a link to a full description.